# Associated table Not getting updated

Tags: java, h2

I'm new to h2 db. I'm populating (inserting) some data in Table A. So whenever I add some data in Table A ,How would I ensure that Table B should also get updated.

**Table A**

```
Prim_Key1   INDEX   NAME    
1            1       A     
2            2       B    
3            3       C
```

**Table B**

```
Prim_Key2   INDEX   Value
```

> Prim_key2--> Populating form XYZ table INDEX--> populating from INDEX
>   of Table A

Here the thing is **I'm populating INDEX of Table A with java trigger.** SO whenever there is new value in Table A, Table B is not getting updated accordingly

Is there any solution to this?

Comment: Are you using a foreign key?

Comment: INDEX column of Table B is the foreign key

Comment: what is java trigger? and what is the meaning of Prim_key2--> Populating form XYZ table INDEX--> populating from INDEX of Table A?

Comment: For java Triggers:- PLz google.  Prim_key2 & INDEX are the columns of Table B where Prim_Key2 Col getting populated from some other table &INDEX column is populating from Table A...or in other words ,they are foreign keys

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

`FOREIGN KEY(INDEX) REFERENCES TABLEA(INDEX) ON UPDATE CASCADE`

This should update the foreign keys as soon as the primary keys in the parent table are updated.

If you want to update some other data(apart from foreign key) as well, then you should try setting up another trigger.